# How to deliver a multilingual FAQ within an app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to ship my app with a built-in FAQ on the settings page. The FAQ is simple:

1) We have a table view which lists all the questions. One per cell.

2) When the user taps one of those questions, we slide over to a detail view controller which shows the question in bold letters and then the answer. Very simple.

The hard part: What would be the optimal way to feed the table view and detail view controller with the strings?

Bad ideas (from my point of view):

- Hardcode all strings and work with giant `if` or `switch` monsters.
- Rely on `NSLocalizedString()` to fetch the localized version of an answer. Those strings files don't look like they were intended for very large strings. Just for a few sentences or words per line. With tons of FAQ text those strings files would become horrifying.

This is how I'd attempt to do it, but you may suggest a better way:

**Solution 1)**

- Create an JSON file where entities have three fields: ID, Question and Answer. ID will help us track down which Answer we have to load after the user tapped a cell.
- Localize that JSON file.
- When the table view loads, read it into memory and parse it, just to read out the questions and ID's (yes, less than ideal, right?)
- When the user taps a cell, either pass the ID just to re-fetch the whole thing again, or maybe better: Pass the ID, question and answer strings to the details view controller.

**Solution 2)**

Like 1, but use Core Data instead. Probably better for memory and performance, but probably harder to maintain (must mess around with a SQLite3 file to build the FAQ, needs at least a good IDE to do that to not go crazy). Caveat: Can't pass it to translators easily. Tons of manual work just to create that SQLite3 file. Files localized in localization folders.

**Solution 4)**

Two splitted JSON files: One with all the ID's and Questions. Another with all the ID's and Answers. Files localized in localization folders.

**Solution 5)**

An JSON file with all the IDs and Questions. For every ID, there's a matching Answer text file. So we don't end up loading tons of data into memory just to extract some tiny fraction of it.

**Solution 6)**

Use something that already exists, or a different approach. Suggestions?

Comment: why XML? use [JSON](http://www.json.org/).  once you start using JSON over XML, you will realize how much time you've wasted parsing xml

Comment: Good point. Thanks for mentioning that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you would localize a `localizedStrings`-file, so that they can get translated when you run `NSLocalizedString`. What you may not know is that this basically works for all kinds of files, so `plist`s too:

1. Create a localized faq `plist`-file.
2. Request it (from in the app) with `[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"faq" ofType:@"plist"]];`
3. Implement it in your `UITableView`. (`- (NSInteger)numberOf...` => `return [faq count];`).

Oh, and I use a `plist`-file instead of JSON or XML since Apple uses it, since it's really easy to implement (`NSArray - arrayWithContentsOfFile` is built in) and you can maintain it very easily in Xcode.

Comment: That's an interesting way of doing it! Thanks! So inside that plist file we have just two columns: Answer and Question. Is that right? Or do we have an "implicit ID" represented by the row in the plist?

Comment: I'ld recommend creating a `array` root-item containing `NSDictionary`-objects with two keys => 'question' and 'answer' and two corresponding values ;)!